# Opening Aerial Image Layers

Tags: qgis, aerial-photography

I cannot seem to open these aerials for Solano County on QGIS. I am using QGIS 3.4 since I'm on Windows 7 and need plugins. I have tried adding XYZ tile layers and ArcGIS Rest Layers, but I don't have any luck and I'm wondering if anyone has some insight on this.

https://solanocountygis.com/portal/home/search.html?q=aerials

Here are the two main aerials I want to add:

https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/SCn6czzcqKAFwdGU/arcgis/rest/services/Aerial2019_CA_NAD83_Z2/MapServer

https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/SCn6czzcqKAFwdGU/arcgis/rest/services/Aerial2019_WGS84_ESRI_Aux/MapServer

Answer (score 0):

Use WMTS (you might not have this in your version)

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/SCn6czzcqKAFwdGU/arcgis/rest/services/Aerial2019_WGS84_ESRI_Aux/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=bfd5129f4dbb6348
```

3.26.0-Buenos Aires used here

[image]